# What does it mean when a private VM page is none of `rwx`?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

**UPDATE**:

It's a padding: every such non-rwx area is preceded with a readable and/or writable area and together they constitute a 64Mb segment (for 64bit architecture).

A relevant question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6568043/251311

I have discovered there are plenty of VM segments that don't have any of `rwx` flags, just `p`:

```
7f7e98033000-7f7e9c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
Size:              65332 kB
Rss:                   0 kB
Pss:                   0 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:            0 kB
Anonymous:             0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
```

Any reference on what it means?

Unlike what's described in http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/dataseg.html, it's not a mapping from a shared library since it does not have a corresponding fd attached. It's a custom long running C++ daemon, but I found some other processes have similar usage patterns: eg erlang (which also has plenty of them). In contrast long running php-fpm and python processes have literally 0 of such segments. "What other mappings does it have?" --- everything else is kind of expected and usual: just normal r/w private segments and shared libraries.

Comment: @Gilles I've run through the links in your answer (especially the http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/dataseg.html which is a gem), do you think it has the same nature as with shared libraries? Eg: it's done by a linker (or something else) to enforce placement of something separated from something else? My extremely limited understanding of memory management allows me understand why it can be helpful for a shared library case, but here it's an anonymous private page. Do you think it's the case here as well?

Comment: Hmm, true, there could be some other reason to have a private page with no permissions (none that comes to mind, but it's technically possible). But what makes you think that this isn't a mapping from a shared library? What process is it? What other mappings does it have?

Comment: It's not a mapping from a shared library since it does not have a corresponding `fd` attached. It's a custom long running C++ daemon, but I found some other processes have similar usage patterns: eg erlang (which also has plenty of them). In contrast long running php-fpm and python processes have literally 0 of such segments. "What other mappings does it have?" --- everything else is kind of expected and usual: just normal `r`/`w` private segments and shared libraries.

Comment: @Gilles seems like it's padding (relevant macro is `HEAP_MAX_SIZE`). Having that keyword I could find something relevant. And what is funny is that you have edited that question as well! :-D http://stackoverflow.com/q/6568043/251311